# Trying to retrieve Rendered Text Width in Raphael

Tags: javascript, jquery, raphael

So I am looking to retrieve the size of a text string in Raphael and I can't seem to do it.  Although the documentation says that

```
.attr('width');
```

is an option...and I can't set the width either.

Here is a [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/videsignz/Rmegm/6/)

This is what I have been trying...plus other crude ways (even using Jquery)

```
var page = Raphael("drawing_board");

    // start, move, and up are the drag functions
    start = function () {
        // storing original coordinates
        this.ox = this.attr("x");
        this.oy = this.attr("y");
        this.attr({opacity: .5});
        console.log( this.attr('width') ); //THIS IS WHERE I AM TRYING TO GET THE WIDTH
    },
    move = function (dx, dy) {
        // move will be called with dx and dy

            nowX = Math.min(600, this.ox + dx);
            nowY = Math.min(400, this.oy + dy);
            nowX = Math.max(0, nowX);
            nowY = Math.max(0, nowY);
            this.attr({x: nowX, y: nowY });

    },
    up = function () {
        // restoring state
        this.attr({opacity: 1});

    };   

    page.text(200, 50, "TEXT 1").attr({ cursor: "move", 'font-size': 16  , fill: '#3D6AA2'}).drag(move, start, up);
    page.text(200, 200, "TEXT 2").attr({ cursor: "move", 'font-size': 16  , fill: '#3D6AA2'}).drag(move, start, up);
```

Maybe I need to use something other than

```
this.attr('width' : 30); //To Set
this.attr('width'); //To Get
```

Comment: You can try with `this.node.getComputedTextLength()` : http://jsfiddle.net/LzvS4/ and http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/text.html#__svg__SVGTextContentElement__getComputedTextLength

Comment: With the answers below, I can't help but wonder if there is a setBBox() function.  Don't mind me, I just started to look into svg this morning. I'm a super newbie.

Comment: no, that method doesn't exist. If you want to "enlarge" an element for example, you need to apply a transformation.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use:

```
this.node.getBBox().width
```

`this.node` -> gets the SVG element associated with the Raphael element
`getBBox()` -> bounding box

You can also use Raphael's `getBBox` method directly:

```
this.getBBox().width
```

Your approach doesn't work because the [svg text element](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/text.html#TextElement) doesn't have a width attribute.

Comment: +1 This definitely works, even without putting 'node' in. Is there a reason not to remove it?

Comment: You should remove node and use Raphael's getBBox function, else it will not account for text alignment in IE (VML)

Comment: I didn't know Raphael provided that method, but now that you mention it, it sounds more appropriate to call it directly.

Answer (score 3):

`this.getBBox()` is the RaphaelJS method to get the computed bbox thus returning an object with `x` `y` `x1` `x2` `width` and `height` properties. It's as cross browser as Raphaeljs is.

Comment: +1 This is awesome...I like how it retrieves many values. Very very useful!

Answer (score 0):

SVG Text elements doesn't have the `width` attribute. Check it on the w3c SVG specification: http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/text.html#TextElement There's no `width` on the attributes list, so you can't set it.

But we could get the `width` of the DOM element with `jQuery`. It can be done first retrieving the DOM element reference and passing it to the `jQuery` constructor, then using the `width()` function. Here's the updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Rmegm/8/

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion...though the updated fiddle you provided only returns '0'

Comment: Not a right approach. Using getBBox of Raphael or the node is the way to go.